# Rank of a sample correlation matrix

Tags: matrix-rank, correlation

I have been working to prove the rank of a sample correlation matrix. Let $%
X_{t}$ be $n\times k$ matrix of observation, where $n>k.$ We assume $%
rank\left( X_{t}\right) =k,$ i.e., $X_{t}$ is column full rank for all $%
t=1,...m$. Let $S_{XX}=\frac{1}{nm}\sum_{t=1}^{m}X_{t}X_{t}^{T},$ i.e., $%
S_{XX}$ is a $n\times n$ matrix. Assuming both $n$ and $m$ are large and $k$
is finite, say, $n,m=100,$ and $k=5.\,$What's the rank of $S_{XX}?$ I tried
some simulations and found the rank of $S_{XX}$ is $k,$ but I don't know how
to prove it. Thanks.

There is a similar question [What is the rank of correlation matrix and its estimate?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2093798/what-is-the-rank-of-correlation-matrix-and-its-estimate) claim the rank of $S_{XX}$ is $k$, but can we prove it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: $X_t X_t^\top$ has rank $k$ for each $t$ (e.g., [see this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349738/prove-operatornamerankata-operatornameranka-for-any-a-in-m-m-times-n) ). Without more information, I don't think we can say anything about the rank of the sum.

Comment: I can assume $X_t$ is uncorrelated over $t$. Do I need any other assumptions on $X_t$? Thanks