# Rank of the sum of rank-1 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

Related question here: [Rank of sum of rank-1 matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707209/rank-of-sum-of-rank-1-matrices)

It looks like my question is a generalisation of the linked question I think.

Suppose I have a $k\times n$ matrix $A$ where $k \geq n$ and suppose that $\mathrm{rank}(A) = m\ (\leq n \leq k)$.

Write $r_1,\dots r_k$ for the rows of $A$ and consider the $n\times n$ matrix
$$
B = r_1^Tr_1 + \cdots + r_k^Tr_k.
$$
Is it true that
$$
\mathrm{rank}(B) = m? 
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: your matrix $B$ is $A^TA$ and therefore has the same rank as $A$.