# $\lambda_{\min}$ and $\lambda_{\max}$ of rank-1 sum of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, projection-matrices, rank-1-matrices

It is explained from previous posts<sup>[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/707209),[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/55165)</sup> that for a rank-$1$ matrix $x_ix_i^T$ we have $\lambda_{\max} (x_ix_i^T)=1$ and $\lambda_{\min} (x_ix_i^T)=0$  with single and $N-1$ algebraic multiplicity, respectively.

Could you please provide some help to compute the $\lambda_{\min}(A)$ and $\lambda_{\max}(A)$ of $$A=\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_ix_j^T$$ with $x_j\in\mathbb{R}^{N}$, $x_j^Tx_j=1$, $x_i^Tx_j=0, i\neq j$ and $n < N$.

Comment: Are you willing to assume that $x_{i}^{T}x_{j}=0$ for $i \neq j$?

Comment: I think in the first part of the proof I am trying to make it is ok but any comment in the case they are not independent are welcome :). Thanks for the interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still $0$ and $1$. Your $A$ is a projection: $A^2=A$, so its eigenvalues need to satisfy $\lambda^2=\lambda $; thus the only possible eigenvalues are $0$ and $1$. And both eigenvalues are realized, since $Ax_1=x_1$, and $Ax_N=0$.

Comment: Interesting approach with the projection, thanks. So there are $n$ eigen-values all equal to 1 and $N-n$ all equal to zero? Thus , the $tr(A)=n$?

Comment: @darkmoor that is correct.